# GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/getLogout 500 (Internal Server Error) [closed]

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, axios, fetch

tengo un problema con las peticiones fetch el cual sale este error GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/getLogout 500 (Internal Server Error).

Déjenme contarles un poco lo que estoy haciendo, cree un api con Node.js en la cual me encuentro utilizando express y mongose, compre todas las rutas con Postman, todas andaban bien, por lo tanto, pasamos a crear el front de la aplicación con React.js, cree los componentes y cree una carpeta Utils en la cual van las consultas al api, utilizando fetch.

Todas las consultas me arrojan el mismo error, intente utilizar Axios también, pero no funciono.

Este es un ejemplo de una de las consultas creadas por mi, esta es método get y no recibe parametros

```
export async function getLogaut() {
  return await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/getLogout`)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Este es el mismo codigo pero creado por Postman

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/getLogout", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Estas llamadas a la api las ejecuto desde un componente con un evento click, que la verdad no hace al caso.

Comment: El error 500 indica que algo está mal en el servidor y no importa si usas `fetch`, `axios`, `postman` o cualquier otro método para conectar, incluso tratando de ingresar directo desde el navegador, seguramente vas a seguir viendo el mismo error.

Comment: Genial gracias Triby y eso como lo puedo solucionar? tiene que ver con la aplicación creada en el back?

Comment: Efectivamente, es error en la aplicación (backend)